# Spark 1.6.1: creating DataFrame from RDD[Array[Error]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've ran into an issue when trying to create a DataFrame in a scala app I'm writing.

Issue I'm having is that compiling scala exits with error that toDF isn't a part of RDD. I've seen answers that suggest moving case class definition out of main and importing implicits after sqlContext declaration, but even that didn't work for me.

This is what I currently have:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object ErrorParser {

    case class Error(time: String, status: String, statusType: String, host: String, message: String)

    def splitError(line: String) : Array[String] = {

        var array:Array[String] = new Array[String](5)

        ...

        return array

    }

    def filterErrors(errors: Array[Array[String]]) : Array[Array[String]] = {

        var filteredErrors = ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()

        ...

        return filteredErrors.toArray
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ErrorParserAPI")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
        import sqlContext.implicits._

        var logs = sc.textFile("hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/logs/data/logs/server.*")
        var errors = logs.filter(line => line.contains("ERROR"))

        val errors1 = errors.map(line => splitError(line))
        val filteredErrors = filterErrors(errors1.collect)

        val dfErrors = filteredErrors.map(p => Error(p(0).split(":")(0) + ":" + p(0).split(":")(1), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4)))
        val filteredRDD = sc.parallelize(dfErrors)
        var errorDF = filteredRDD.toDF()

        errorDF.write.json("hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/results/errorParserResult")

   }

}
```

I'm stumped since in spark-shell things work like this.

I've also seen some answers that suggest changing RDD to an instance of RDD[Row] and then using

```
sc.createDataFrame(rdd, scheme)
```

but I can't wrap my head around how I would go around doing that.

Any help would be much appreciated!

This is my .sbt file:

```
name := "ErrorParserAPI"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.1",
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.1"
)
```

EDIT: a typo

Comment: did you try to move your case class `Error` definition out from object  `ErrorParser`? Regardless of the issue, it would be good idea, since inner class captures outer scope, that may lead to problems with serialization. Also, try to avoid code like this ` filterErrors(errors1.collect)` - it's better to write `filterErrors` in form of predicate and use it like `errors`.filter(isError)`

Comment: thanks for the heads-up on the filterErrors implementation, will try to move case class out and see how it goes

Comment: sadly moving case class outside of object did not resolve the issue @VitaliyKotlyarenko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied your code and pasted in my eclipse and its working fine without any compilation errors . If you are using eclipse , you may try cleaning and refreshing your project.

```
import scala.Array.canBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object ErrorParser {


  def filterErrors(errors: Array[Array[String]]): Array[Array[String]] = {

    var filteredErrors = ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()

    return filteredErrors.toArray
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {



    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ErrorParserAPI")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    var logs = sc.textFile("hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/logs/data/logs/server.*")
    var errors = logs.filter(line => line.contains("ERROR"))

    val errors1 = errors.map(line => splitError(line))
    val filteredErrors = filterErrors(errors1.collect)

    val dfErrors = filteredErrors.map(p => Error(p(0).split(":")(0) + ":" + p(0).split(":")(1), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4)))
    val filteredRDD = sc.parallelize(dfErrors)
    var errorDF = filteredRDD.toDF()
  }

  case class Error(time: String, status: String, statusType: String, host: String, message: String)

  def splitError(line: String): Array[String] = {

    var array: Array[String] = new Array[String](5)

    return array

  }
}
```

Comment: Building .jar file in eclipse and then deploying it to spark worked. Still don't know what the core issue was but i'll mark it as an answer for now.